# Create subsets in a loop according to a column values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, subset, levels

I have a dataframe of which I wan't to create subsets in a loop according to the values of one column.

Here is an example df :

```
c1        c2      c3
A          1       2
A          2       2
B          0       2
B          1       1
```

I would like to create subsets like so in a loop

first iteration, select all rows in which C1=A, and only columns 2 and 3, second, all rows in which C1=B, and only C2 and 3.

I've tried the following code :

```
for level in enumerate(df.loc[:,"C1"].unique()):

    df_s = df.loc[df["C1"]==level].iloc[:, 1:len(df.columns)]
    #other actions on the subsetted dataframe
```

but the subset isn't performed.
How to iterate throudh the levels of a column

For instance in R it would be

```
for (le in levels(df$C1){
dfs <- df[df$C1==le,2:ncol(df)]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for the `enumerate` which gives both index and values, just loop through `c1` column directly:

```
for level in df.c1.unique():
    df_s = df.loc[df.c1 == level].drop('c1', 1)
    print(level + ":\n", df_s)

#A:
#    c2  c3
#0   1   2
#1   2   2
#B:
#    c2  c3
#2   0   2
#3   1   1
```

---

Most likely, what you need is `df.groupby('c1').apply(lambda g: ...)`, which should be a more efficient approach; Here `g` is the sub data frame with a unique `c1` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
for level in df.loc[:,"c1"].unique():
    print(level)
    df_s = df.loc[df["c1"]==level,:].iloc[:,1:len(df)]

    print(df_s)

A
   c2  c3
0   1   2
1   2   2
B
   c2  c3
2   0   2
3   1   1
```

Or ( this one is more like R )

```
for level in df.loc[:,"c1"].unique():
    print(level)
    df_s = df.loc[df["c1"]==level,df.columns[1:len(df)]]
    print(df_s)
```

Comment: I was searching also on how to subset rows and columns in the same call instead of my .loc and .iloc in the same line of code.

Comment: @Boidot you can check Psidom's answer.